# How to detect if app is inactive in mac application

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I need to display alerts in the app, and if app is inactive I need to use `NSUserNotification` to send out alerts else I will use a simple sheetModal alert dialog. How can I know if the application is active or inactive ? i.e user is actively using the app or using some other app  ?

I need to replicate same alert system as in Xcode, if Xcode is active it shows a message on Xcode window else it will post a UserNotification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read the Docs on [NSApplicaion](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

In it you will see

**[isActive](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000012-CACCJFFJ)**

```
Returns a Boolean value indicating whether this is the active application.

- (BOOL)isActive
Return Value
YES if this is the active application; NO otherwise.
```

Answer (score 2):

How about `applicationWillResignActive:`:

> Sent by the default notification center immediately before the
>   application is deactivated.

Check out Apple's documentation on [the NSApplicationDelegate protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSApplicationDelegate/applicationWillResignActive%3a).

Comment: Good idea. :-) forgot about that.